# TSQL Ordering spanning over midnight

Tags: t-sql, time-series

I am having problem trying to order a TSQL table as below based on the departure time to the arrival time if it passes over midnight.

As you can see I am sorting by the time column so earliest to latest, but there is a flag on the left under **location_type** that states that the first departure is the **LO** row. So it should start from this and end on the **LT** row.

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ location_type           nlcdesc                         arrival     pass    departure   time ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ LI                      WILLESDEN BRENT SDGS (FL)       0110        0110    NULL        0110 ║
║ LI                      WEST LONDON JN                  NULL        0204    NULL        0204 ║
║ LI                      NORTH JUNCTION                  NULL        0322    NULL        0322 ║
║ LI                      RUGBY TRENT VALLEY JUNCTION     NULL        0405    NULL        0405 ║
║ LT                      SPEKE JN                        0430        NULL    NULL        0430 ║
║ LO                      LIVERPOOL GARSTON FRTLNR DEPOT  NULL        NULL    2153        2153 ║
║ LI                      ACTON BRIDGE                    NULL        2223    NULL        2223 ║
║ LI                      STAFFORD                        NULL        2255    NULL        2255 ║
║ LI                      CHANNELSEA JN                   NULL        2331    NULL        2331 ║
║ LI                      DAGENHAM DOCK                   NULL        2355    NULL        2355 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So what I want the results to look like is this

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ location_type           nlcdesc                         arrival     pass    departure   time ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ LO                      LIVERPOOL GARSTON FRTLNR DEPOT  NULL        NULL    2153        2153 ║
║ LI                      ACTON BRIDGE                    NULL        2223    NULL        2223 ║
║ LI                      STAFFORD                        NULL        2255    NULL        2255 ║
║ LI                      CHANNELSEA JN                   NULL        2331    NULL        2331 ║
║ LI                      DAGENHAM DOCK                   NULL        2355    NULL        2355 ║
║ LI                      WILLESDEN BRENT SDGS (FL)       0110        0110    NULL        0110 ║
║ LI                      WEST LONDON JN                  NULL        0204    NULL        0204 ║
║ LI                      NORTH JUNCTION                  NULL        0322    NULL        0322 ║
║ LI                      RUGBY TRENT VALLEY JUNCTION     NULL        0405    NULL        0405 ║
║ LT                      SPEKE JN                        0430        NULL    NULL        0430 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

As you can see it Starts with the departure row flagged with the LO and ends  with the arrival row flagged with the LT. Spanning over the midnight 2355 to 0110 rows

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` like:

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30dea/1/0)**

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY
  CASE 
     WHEN [time] >= 1200 AND [time] <=2359 THEN 0
     ELSE 1
  END ASC
  ,[time]
```

You can set the starting `[time] >=1200` as you wish for example `1800`.